# Find all occurences of space characters between specific tags

Tags: regex

I have a string like this

```
"<content>    </content><p>some content</p><content>     </content>"
```

I have added 4 space characters between the 1st content tag and 5 space characters in between the second content tag. So in all there are 9 space characters.

I want a regular expression that will exactly match all the space characters in between the content tag.

I have tried this

```
/<content> +<\/content>/g
```

But this gives me 2 matches. I want 9 matches for the 9 space characters. What would the right regular expression be?

Comment: Can there be characters other than space in the content tag? Are there always 4 or 5 spaces? If not, is there a maximum number of spaces? What are the tokens you want to replace the spaces - characters or longer strings? Are all tokens the same, or different for different lengths of spaces, or different for every single space?

Comment: Yes there can be other characters. But I want to find only those content tags which have spaces in them. And each space character has to be replaced by some token which is a longer string. And this token is the same for every space character.

Answer (score 0):

It's giving you 2 matches because there are two occurrences of the `<content>` tag (opening and closing) with spaces in between.

What you need is something like:

```
for (/<content>( +)<\/content>/g) {
    print length $1;
}
```

That will capture the spaces between the tags and print out the length of that string (in essence, the number of spaces).

Comment: But actually I need to find and replace the spaces between content tags with some token. With the above solution after finding the spaces I will have to again replace  the tags with tokens in the original string. I want to use php's `preg_replace` to replace space characters in the content tags

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use php's `preg_replace` to replace space characters in the
>   content tags

I don't think it can be done with only a `preg_replace`. I suggest:

```
$str = "<content>    </content><p>some content</p><content>     </content>";
$str = preg_replace_callback('-<content>.*?</content>-',
                             function($found)
                             { return str_replace(' ', 'TOK', $found[0]); },
                             $str
                            );
```